# What are some good software packages for Technical Analysis?

Tags: software, technical-analysis

What are software packages that allow me to perform technical analysis on candlestick charts?  Ideally the software will update with realtime stock data.

I'm mostly using Windows but am also curious about Android apps.  It can be a web app too.

I'm sure a bunch exist, but I just started looking and Googling mostly brings up broker sites that offer tools.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Software Recommendations StackExchange.. but try ThinkorSwim. You will need an account with TDAmeritrade for realtime data otherwise you can use a paper money account that has 15 minute delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 10 years ago, I used to use [MetaStock Trader](http://www.metastock.com/) which was a very sound tool, with a large number of indicators, but it has been a number of years since I have used it, so my comments on it will be out of date. At the time it relied upon me purchasing trading data myself, which is why I switched to Incredible Charts.

I currently use [Incredible Charts](https://www.incrediblecharts.com/) which I have done for a number of years, initially on the free adware service, now on the $10/year for EOD data access. There are quicker levels of data access, which might suit you, but I can't comment on these. It is web-based which is key for me. The data quality is very good and the number of inbuilt indicators is excellent. You can build search routines on the basis of specific indicators which is very effective.

I'm looking at [VectorVest](http://www.vectorvest.co.uk/), as a replacement for (or in addition to) Incredible Charts, as it has very powerful backtesting routines and the ability to run test portfolios with specific buy/sell criteria that can simulate and backtest a number of trading scenarios at the same time.

The advantage of all of these is they are not tied to a particular broker.